# Rename / replace data in a column with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset and i trying to use mutate to replace or rename the data inside a column given different conditions.

I have generate a summary using code:

> `summary(s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv)`

and show beclow info.

[image]

I am trying to make the changes as follow:

- 1 becomes "Some High School"
- 2 becomes "High School"
- 3 becomes "Vocational School"
- 4 becomes "College"

But i only can change 1 of the category and if i repeat using below code, the previous converted value become NA.

> ```
> s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv_edu <- s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv %>% 
>   mutate(Education = ifelse(as.character(Education) == "1", "Some High School", as.factor(Education)))
> ```

Comment: You could use `dplyr::recode` ([docu](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html), which exists exactly for that purpose)

Comment: I think i manage to find an answer s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv_edu <- s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv %>%
  mutate(Education = ifelse(Education == "1", "Some High School", Education)) %>% 
  mutate(Education = ifelse(Education == "2", "High School", Education)) %>% 
  mutate(Education = ifelse(Education == "3", "Vocational School", Education)) %>%
  mutate(Education = ifelse(Education == "4", "College", Education))